# Why does this terminal command for screen unzip instantly return a "Screen is terminating" message instead of unzipping?

Tags: macos, terminal, unzip

```
screen unzip 'filess3x-September-9-2016-at-12-52-05-PM.zip' -d '~/Volumes/L/e/x-September-9-2016-at-10-51-47-AM'
```

gives me a message

> [screen is terminating]

but no unzipped file. How to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

The `unzip` command is caught by the signal that closes the hidden window of `screen`, and discards the file as if you had interrupted `unzip` intentionally.  You could work around this by wrapping the command in a shell script which catches signals, and allows it to exit gracefully.